# Does Tornado AsyncHTTPClient support persistance connection?

Tags: python, http, tornado

Does Tornado **AsyncHTTPClient** support persistance(Keep-Alive) connection? The official document is not so clear for this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (when using `simple_httpclient`), persistent connections are not currently supported (as of Tornado 4.2). When configured to use `curl_httpclient`, persistent connections are supported.

```
AsyncHTTPClient.configure('tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient')
```